# IIS Rejecting Requests Missing Content-Length

Tags: iis-8

I am integrating with a third party who has a heartbeat running to make sure my site is up. They are doing a POST to a URL but they don't include the Content-Length. IIS Rejects it with a 411.

I am trying to turn off this behavior in IIS for this path. Was thinking I could use URL Rewriting to just respond with 200, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any help or ideas appreciated

Comment: IIS is completely correct; that's an illegal request.

Comment: @SLaks i know but I don't have control over the sender,

Comment: Looks like URL Rewriting won't work the request must be getting rejected earlier in the pipeline

Comment: Also not sure if it's even getting to .net. The requests don't show up in the trace.axd.

Comment: Yes; you won't easily be able to make IIS process an illegal request.  You should complain to the sender.

Comment: I have, they told me to setup another server and redirect to me. Will find another provider before I go that route.